# Simulating the transition of packages in a distribution line

Tags: python, loops, simulation

I am new to python and am trying to run a simulation of a warehouse logistics. The problem is composed of four main agents:
a shed, trucks, motorcycles and a distribution line. The truck enters the shed in one side with a specified amount of boxes, it goes to center of the shed, stops and start unloading the boxes to the distribution line, the distribution line moves the boxes to the other side of the shed where motorcycles pickup one box each. 
The objective is to vary the size of the shed and distribution line to find the shape that can deliver more boxes in fixed amount of time (or compute the time taken to distribute a fixed amount of boxes, as in my code for now)

The distribution line is a rectangle, a grid with variable amount of rows and columns, depending on the size of the shed, let's say each cell has 0,50m on each side.

In the code I simulated the truck passing through the shed, and the amount of trucks passing as iterations, the problems is:

how to simulate the boxes moving through the grid (distribution line) from one side to the other, maybe accumulating in the stock until a bike arrives, and have the motorcycles "grab" them and go out after the boxes arrive?

I tried to count the boxes with "+= 1" function but I don't know why it's not working (would not be very realistic as well)

This is the main code:

```py
import time
from Vehicles import Truck, Motorbike

bike1 = Motorbike(10, 1)
truck1 = Truck(10, int(input("Enter how many loads the truck has: ")))
num_iterations = int(input("Enter number of iterations: "))

start = time.time()

shed_width = 4
shed_length = 12
truck_path = int(shed_length * truck1.truck_speed/2)

for n in range(num_iterations):
    truck_middle = False
    while truck_middle is not True:
        for i in range(truck_path):
            x = 100/truck_path
            if i == truck_path/2:
                truck_middle = True
            else:
    #the bar here is to just have some visual feedback while the code runs
                print("\r[%-60s] %d%%" % ('=' * i, x * i), end='')
                time.sleep(0.1)

        print("\ntruck is in the middle")
        truck_middle = True

    # while truck_middle is True:
    #     box = 0
    #     if box < truck1.truck_load:
    #         box += 1
    #     else:
    #         truck_middle = False
    print("This was iteration: " + str(n+1))
    time.sleep(0.01)


end = time.time()

print("\nDone! \nThe simulation took " + str(end - start) + " seconds to complete!")
```

I also created a class in a file called "Vehicles" for the truck and the motorcycles, where I can define their speed and the load they can carry:

```py
class Truck:
    def __init__(self, truck_speed, truck_load):
        self.truck_speed = truck_speed
        self.truck_load = truck_load

class Motorbike:
    def __init__(self, motorbike_speed, motorbike_load):
        self.motorbike_speed = motorbike_speed
        self.motorbike_load = motorbike_load
```

I am open to code suggestions, indications of libraries and other resources I can search and study, any help will be much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
box = 0
while truck_middle == True:

    if box < truck1.truck_load:
        box += 1
    else:
        truck_middle = False
```

In your way, `box` will always be `1` and `truck_middle` is always  `True`, and it goes in a dead loop